# Show only the last two year digits in Biblatex citation

Tags: biblatex

I'm writing a piece where I'm citing several standards, for example

```
@STANDARD{en1990,
  title = {EN 1990: Eurocode: Basis of Structural Design},
  organization = {Comit\'e Europ\'een de Normalisation (CEN)},
  address = {Brussels, Belgium},
  year = {2002}
}
```

and

```
@STANDARD{aci318-63,
  title = {ACI 318-63: Building Code Requirements for Reinforced Concrete},
  organization = {American Concrete Institute (ACI)},
  address = {Farmington Hills, Michigan, USA},
  year = {1963}
}
```

I use `biblatex` with `style=authoryear`. I can cite the first one as `\parencite*[EN 1990:][]{en1990}`, which causes the citation to appear as `(EN 1990: 2002)` in running text, which is the way this standard is usually cited. However, this won't work for the second example, since this standard is styled as `ACI 318-63` and `\parencite*` will only produce the whole year instead of only the last digits.

Is there a way to change the way the year is formatted for a certain citation? Even better, is there a way to override/modify the default citation text?

I kind of suspect I'd need to create a custom style with an extra field that holds the formatted year as it should appear in the citation, but I hope there's an easy way to do it without spending too much time customizing `biblatex` styles.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of using the second optional citation argument to produce a "short title", I would use the `shorttitle` field. Then, dependent on whether you have added the last digits of the year to `shorttitle` or not, I would either use `\parencite` (the non-starred version) or a custom `\parencitetitle` command.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencitetitle}[\mkbibparens]
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexfield{indextitle}}
     {}%
%   \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\parencitetitle}[\mkbibparens]
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexfield{indextitle}}
     {}%
%   \printfield[citetitle]{title}}
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{title}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@STANDARD{en1990,
  shorttitle = {EN 1990},
  title = {EN 1990: Eurocode: Basis of Structural Design},
  organization = {Comit\'e Europ\'een de Normalisation (CEN)},
  address = {Brussels, Belgium},
  year = {2002},
}
@STANDARD{aci318-63,
  shorttitle = {ACI 318-63},
  title = {ACI 318-63: Building Code Requirements for Reinforced Concrete},
  organization = {American Concrete Institute (ACI)},
  address = {Farmington Hills, Michigan, USA},
  year = {1963},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \parencite{en1990}.

Some text \parencite{aci318-63}.

Some text \parencitetitle{en1990}.

Some text \parencitetitle{aci318-63}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can define a new formatting directive that prints the last two digits in a year, but you would need to customize the style to incorporate it.

Use of fields that form the citation label is another approach that avoids style changes. The `label` field is used as a fallback in `authoryear` whenever `author` or `year` are unavailable. The `shorthand` field overrides the entire citation label.

The document below gives some examples. You'll probably want to experiment with the `label`, `shorthand`, `title` and `execute` fields to avoid repetition of data in your bibliography.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xpatch}% Only needed for optional patch below

\DeclareFieldFormat{shortyear}{\mkbibshortyear#1}
\def\mkbibshortyear#1#2#3#4{#3#4}

\newrobustcmd*{\citeshortyear}{%
  \AtNextCite{\DeclareFieldAlias{year}{shortyear}}%
  \citeyear}

% Customize label-year delimiter in cite bibmacro
\newcommand*{\labelyeardelim}{\addspace}
\xpatchbibmacro{cite}
  {\setunit{\addspace}}{\setunit{\labelyeardelim}}{}{}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@STANDARD{en1990,
  shorthand = {EN 1990: 2001},
  execute = {\ifbibliography{\clearfield{year}}{}},
  title = {Eurocode: Basis of Structural Design},
  organization = {Comit\'e Europ\'een de Normalisation (CEN)},
  address = {Brussels, Belgium},
  year = {2001}}
@STANDARD{en1990label,
  label = {EN 1990},
  execute = {\renewcommand*{\labelyeardelim}{\addcolon\space}},
  title = {Eurocode: Basis of Structural Design},
  organization = {Comit\'e Europ\'een de Normalisation (CEN)},
  address = {Brussels, Belgium},
  year = {2002}}
@STANDARD{aci318-63,
  shorthand = {ACI 318-63},
  title = {Building Code Requirements for Reinforced Concrete},
  organization = {American Concrete Institute (ACI)},
  address = {Farmington Hills, Michigan, USA},
  year = {1963}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newcommand{\cmd}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash #1}}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\cmd{citeyear}: \citeyear{en1990,en1990label,aci318-63} \\
\cmd{citeshortyear}: \citeshortyear{en1990,en1990label,aci318-63} \\
\cmd{parencite}: \parencite{en1990,en1990label,,aci318-63} \\
\cmd{textcite}: \textcite{en1990,en1990label,aci318-63}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I kind of like your solution better because it works with `hyperref` out of the box.

Comment: Your bibliography ends up looking funny without some adjustments to the titles. I'll post an edit in a bit.

Comment: @MartinTapankov See my updated answer.